# how to get a string inside two different delimiters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, split, delimiter

as for the question, is that even possible?
I am working on this..
[image]

it should only be "UP" in there, but since my delimiter is = it only reads = , so it continued getting the second line which is DHCP.

here is my code..

```
Private Sub btnSettings_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click
    Dim str As String = rtb.Text
    Dim star() As String

        star = str.Split("="c)
        txtIP.Text = star(1)

End Sub
```

is there a way that I can get a string in between different delimiters? 
for example =  192.168.254.238  :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it on some c# page in stackoverflow.
just added another delimiter although I don't know if it will work with three. cheers!

```
Private Sub btnSettings_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click
    Dim str As String = rtb.Text
    Dim star() As String
    ''Dim starr() As String
    star = str.Split("="c, ":"c)
    ''starr = str.Split(":"c)
    txtIP.Text = star(4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yours will be shorter code and faster. But what if one of the upper values has = and : ? For example `DHCP=:ON`. I know this is highly unlikely but if human is involve this is not impossible. Secondly, you have star(4), what if it should be in star(2)? So, that's why it's good to traverse the lines and then get the one that you exactly need with little possibility of error. But again yours is indeed shorter and if it serves your purpose then go ahead ;-)

Comment: so basically, I need to change the toUpper part and all the indexes in your code? well, that seems to be better. with my code, I need to clear the rtb first so that it will overlap and update. thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you want here, but try this one:

```
 For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
     Dim star() As String = line.Split("=")
     If (star(0).ToUpper() = "IP") Then
         If (star(1).IndexOf(":") >= 0) Then
            txtIP.Text = star(1).Substring(0, star(1).IndexOf(":"))
         Else
            txtIP.Text = star(1)
         End If
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: that sure did the thing, but I happen to find something simpler.
     'star=str.Split("="c,":"c)'
     'txtIP.text=star(1)'
they seem to share the same results, but I know they will do different things further. can you tell me the difference? and what should I properly use?

Answer (score 0):

first split on `vbcrlf` - you get the lines, then `for-each` line, split on `=` - you get the key/values.